# Docker compose containers shutting down after I log out

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Running docker compose -d on a handful of containers set to restart: always (it was unless-stopped, changing it to always did not solve the problem). Ubuntu is my OS.

I have found that a few hours after logging out my docker containers stop responding to requests. There is nothing in the logs, they just seem to stop and not report anything untoward. Except deluge, the front end complains that it cannot connect to deluged.

Services run outside of docker continue to run as normal. I'm fairly novice adjacent when it comes to docker, so I am probably missing something simple. Any thoughts?

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
services:
 radarr:
  container_name: radarr
  restart: always
  ports:
   - 7878:7878
  volumes:
    - ~/docker/servarr/radarr/config:/config
    - ~/media:/media
    - ~/downloads:/downloads
  environment:
   - PUID=1000
   - PGID=1000
   - TZ=America/New_York
  image: linuxserver/radarr

 sonarr:
  container_name: sonarr
  ports:
   - 8989:8989
  volumes:
    - ~/docker/servarr/sonarr/config:/config
    - ~/media:/media
    - ~/downloads:/downloads
  environment:
   - PUID=1000
   - PGID=1000
   - TZ=America/New_York
  image: linuxserver/sonarr
  restart: always

 deluge:
  image: lscr.io/linuxserver/deluge:latest
  container_name: deluge
  environment:
   - PUID=1000
   - PGID=1000
   - TZ=Etc/UTC
   - DELUGE_LOGLEVEL=error
  volumes:
   - ~/docker/servarr/deluge/config:/config
   - ~/downloads:/downloads
  ports:
   - 8112:8112
   - 6881:6881
   - 6881:6881/udp
   - 58846:58846
  restart: always

 flaresolverr:
  image: ghcr.io/flaresolverr/flaresolverr:latest
  container_name: flaresolverr
  environment:
   - LOG_LEVEL=${LOG_LEVEL:-info}
   - LOG_HTML=${LOG_HTML:-false}
   - CAPTCHA_SOLVER=${CAPTCHA_SOLVER:-none}
   - TZ=Europe/London
  ports:
   - 8191:8191
  volumes:
   - ~/docker/flaresolverr/config:/config
  restart: always

 prowlarr:
  container_name: prowlarr
  image: cr.hotio.dev/hotio/prowlarr
  ports:
   - 9696:9696
  environment:
   - PUID=1000
   - PGID=1000
   - UMASK=002
   - TZ=Etc/UTC
  volumes:
   - ~/docker/prowlarr/config:/config
  restart: always

 mylar3:
  image: lscr.io/linuxserver/mylar3:latest
  container_name: mylar3
  environment:
   - PUID=1000
   - PGID=1000
   - TZ=Etc/UTC
  volumes:
   - ~/docker/mylar/config:/config
   - ~/media:/media #optional
   - ~/downloads:/downloads
  ports:
   - 8090:8090
  restart: always

 sabnzbd:
  image: lscr.io/linuxserver/sabnzbd:latest
  container_name: sabnzbd
  environment:
   - PUID=1000
   - PGID=1000
   - TZ=Etc/UTC
  volumes:
   - ~/docker/servarr/sabnzb:/config
   - ~/downloads:/downloads
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
  restart: always
```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue anytime? Enter to the container and try  the http endpoints with curl or wget and localhost. Share us the result

Comment: *"a few hours after logging out"*  seems not necessarly be connected to you logging out. What happens if you don't log out?

Comment: @derpirscher Well, Ill let you know in a few hours as I am logged in currently. Though strangely I have not restarted the containers, but they are up now so idk wtf is happening.

Comment: @JRichardsz at the moment everything is running fine, will try that when the issue repeats itself. Tho during the period where they are 'sleeping' they are not logging anything so I do not beleive them to be actively running at all.

if services NOT in containers stopped running I would swear that the vm was just in a paused state

Comment: @JRichardsz note that I did not restart the containers as per my above comment. They are just working now, after logging in

Comment: and ofc now that Ive decided to actually investigate the issue it seems to have stopped happening